# Cant get Kivy to work in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, kivy

As stated above i cant seem to work with kivy while using Visual Studio Code. I can see that there are a few other posts like this one but im not sure if they are the same problem or not so until im notified that i need to move my post i wont.

So i am working through the book Creating Apps in Kivy Mobile with Python, I am at the very first example. i will post my code and the output from my terminal and hopefully someone can help.

heres the code

first file main.py

```
from kivy.app import App


class WeatherApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WeatherApp().run()
```

and here is the Kivy file: weather.kv

```
Label:
    text: "Hello World"
```

and lastly here is my output from the terminal

```
$ /Users/fau57/.pyenv/versions/3.9.2/bin/python "/Users/fau57/Documents/Development/Python/Kivy/Creating Apps in Kivy/Practice Code/main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/fau57/Documents/Development/Python/Kivy/Creating Apps in Kivy/Practice Code/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from kivy.app import App
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following command in terminal to install the **kivy** package:

```
pip install kivy
```

[image]

Comment: So this is what my terminal wrote out after i tried pip install kivy
so the output is too long but basically it says that all the dependencies have been met already.. is there another step i need to take?

Comment: Does running the code after installing the package still produce this error(`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'`)?

Answer (score 0):

Some things you might check...

1. Kivy doesn't work with the latest version of Python (3.10) so make sure you're using 3.9.x.
2. The book you're working from was published in 2014 and the code samples were tested with Kivy 1.8. A lot has changed since then and you might consider, instead, using more recent learning material. When I was working my way through "Creating Apps in Kivy Mobile with Python" I only got to page 13 when I ran into a deprecated widget, so I abandoned the book.
3. It's recommended that Kivy be used in a virtual environment, so it's actually simpler to set it up manually and write your code with Notepad++ instead of VS Code. Notepad++ has a syntax highlighter for Kivy. Yes, you'll do more typing, but the more code you type, the better you'll learn. VS Code and its ilk have made us all lazy.